# Como puedo ejecutar SOLO lo seleccionado en python

Tags: python, pycharm

Me gustaría poder seleccionar con el ratón, nose 10 lineas y sólo ejecutar esas 10 lineas. Por ejemplo, en Matlab solo con pulsar F9 puedo hacer esa tarea pero en python no se si existe un shortcut o yo lo puedo personalizar.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si estás usando VSCode como editor, pulsar Mayus+Enter hace eso que dices (si tienes instalada la extensión de Python). Pero naturalmente la pregunta no es de python, sino del IDE que estés usando. Naturalmente si la selección hace uso de variables que habían sido incializadas antes (fuera de la selección) no va a funcionar. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a los Jupyter Notebooks

Comment: Y hay alguna forma de hacerlo en pycharm? 

Comment: Lo que pides significa que el código se ejecutará sin las condiciones previas necesarias: los archivos estarán cerrados, las variables sin inicializar y el resto del programa en un estado indefinido. La alternativa es poner un breakpoint y correrlo en modo depuración para ver que hace exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas para pycharm por defecto puedes hacer clicl derecho y ejecutarlo o usar el shorcut Alt+Mayus+E.
Pudes cambiar el shorcut en File->Settings->Keymaps y dentro de estos buscas Execute Selection in Console para cambiarle el shorcut.

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias gente